# How can I remove Ozone from a sealed enclosure

Tags: chemical-engineering, product-engineering

One of the processes in a current product design catalyzes the conversion of atmospheric oxygen into ozone: 
$$
3\text{O}_2+\text{energy}\rightarrow 2\text{O}_3
$$
[Ozone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone) is highly reactive and, over time, will degrade the components in the sealed enclosure.  One technique which I have read about for removing the ozone is to actively cycle the air in the enclosure through a catalyst such as silver oxide ($\text{Ag}_2\text{O}$) or manganese oxide ($\text{MnO}$).

Given that the enclosed volume is 1-2 liters, is it necessary to actively cycle the air, or can the catalyst simply be placed in the enclosure? Are there any other techniques for ozone removal which I should consider?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the enclosure being sealed? By cycling the air in the enclosure does that then make the enclosure sealed only some of the time? If the enclosure needs to be sealed from the air in the atmosphere could the enclosure be filled with an inert gas such as Argon.

Comment: @Fred It needs to be sealed to keep it free of contaminants, but the seal isn't tight enough to contain an inert gas for the entire life of the product (many years).  The system which would be used to cycle the air past the catalyst would be a closed loop.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to fill and purge the sealed container with an inert gas like nitrogen or argon. Without oxygen present, no ozone will be created. Additional details regarding the origin of the ozone may be helpful.

CFC molecules break down ozone, but are consequently regulated because of it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorofluorocarbon#Regulation